# How to create a 1h long WMV file from a repeated 1 minute WMV many times over?

Tags: video, editing

What's the fastest way to do this? Is there a way I can just copy the file 60 times over without having to re-encode?

It's a WMV file created with Expression Encoder.

Comment: Which version of the video codec does the file have? It may be possible for ffmpeg concat demuxer to do the job.

Comment: Yes, please provide more details on your tools, environment and video specs. It's much easier to write an accurate answer with that in hands. You can [edit] the question to add details.

Comment: Welcome @Zopiro :) Please convert this into an answer.

Comment: This site is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ffmpeg concat demuxer can do this if the WMV video codec variant can be encoded by ffmpeg. Windows Media Video 7 & 8 qualify, Windows Media Video 9 doesn't.